# Google Cloud Storage API access (via JWT server-to-server) "Invalid grant_type" issue

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, make.com

While using integromat.com to try to access GCS I get an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUCCw.png)

The error message might be misleading as the instructed string and sent string are identical:

urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer
urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer

I'm trying to avoid use of OAuth2. Integromat is not registered as a valid endpoint at Google API backend as I understood that would not be necessary when using server-to-server method.

Anyone available and willing to get a mini-contract to dive in on a shared screen together with me to resolve this one?

Best Regards,
Tomas

PS: this is how the failing step looks like on Integromat. "text 68" includes correctly formatted JWT as requested on Google instructions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUlqT.png)

Comment: You cannot bypass OAuth. Once you have a signed JWT from a service account, you exchange it for an Access Token. I wrote an article that shows the details in Python. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looking and testing. It seems that due to the OAuth, we are stuck because our endpoint (https://www.integromat.com/oauth/cb/oauth2) is not set on Google side. Without paid G-suite account it is not possible to use internal setup. External could take weeks or months to get approved by Google.

Comment: You need a Google Cloud Platform account. G Suite has nothing to do with service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your issue, you can use [Single sign-on (SSO)](https://cloud.google.com/identity/sso/). [SSO](https://cloud.google.com/identity/solutions/enable-sso/) is a session and user authentication service that permits a user to use one set of login credentials (e.g., name and password) to access multiple applications. The cloud identity is free, and it will not incur any charges. For more information, please read this [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7431902).